# Perl:How to insert line in a file?

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading from two files. I'm trying to insert a line from file2 to file1 whenever column 1 contents matches.

##FILE1

```
1   wr  5769        78670002    fqefq  
3   wr  5769        78650003    hfhhg  
5   wr  5769        88990001    dfdsv
```

##FILE2

```
1   Step1  
3   Step3  
5   Step5
```

Desired Output:

```
1   wr  5769        78670002    fqefq  
Step1
3   wr  5769        78650003    hfhhg
Step3  
5   wr  5769        88990001    dfdsv
Step5
```

Code tried:

```
my $rk="rk.log";
open(my $tt, "<$rk" ) or die "Could not open file $trk: $!";
    while (<$tt>) {
       if ($_ =~ /^(\d+)\s+wr\s+5769\s+(\w+)\s+\.*/gm) { 
          open(p1,"<$temp1") or die "Could not open file $temp1: $!"; 
              while (my $newl = <p1>) {
                   my @fs1 = split " ", $newl;
                   if ($fs1[0] eq $1){
                      print "@fs1\n";
                      print "step   $2\n";
                      } else {
                      print "@fs1\n";
                   }
             }
        }
  }
close p1;
close $tt;
```

Above code doesn't giving the desired output. Can anyone suggest me better way to do it?

Update ##FILE2

```
2   Step1  
4   Step3  
6   Step5
```

Comment: You have updated File2 in such a way that no lines in it will match your original criteria. So I assume your criteria have changed as well. Without knowing what your new criteria are, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, a bit of pseudocode will be enough to get you on the right track.

- Read file2 into a hash (where the key is the integer and the value is the whole line)
- Open file1
- Read file1 a line at a time

  - Print the line from file1
  - Extract the integer from the start of the line from line1
  - If that integer exists in your hash

    - Print the line from file2

Comment: Your method works if values in the hash exist in file1. If I increment the number in file2 then hash won't work here. Check the update part. Thanks

Comment: @HG If you increment the number in file2, then the lines would no longer match, and according to your original condition the lines should no longer be inserted.

Comment: @TLP Yes, Later I realized in some case some values are incremented.

Comment: @HG Maybe you should update the question and explain the new conditions and add suitable test cases.

Comment: @HG: To be honest, I think that a lot of the problem here might be that you're not actually 100% sure what the specification of the problem is. I feel sure that if you worked that out, then you'd be far better positioned to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest method would be to import the two files into separate strings, then create a loop which:

1. Finds match in file 1. (Include line breaks in your matches)
2. Appends match to third string.
3. Deletes match from file 1. (Replace with nothing)
4. Finds match from file 2. (Include line breaks in your matches)
5. Appends match to third string.
6. Deletes match from file 2.

This way you will sequentially order all of your matches from the two files into a string that you can export as a file.

Comment: My file1 has more than 10k lines and file2 has more that 500 lines, So I think importing both the files to separate strings is not a better way to do. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
use Tie::File;

my $fle1 = $ARGV[0]; my $fle2 = $ARGV[1];

open(FL2, $fle2) || die "Couldn't read file $fle2\: $!\n";
my $flecnt2 = do {  local $/; <FL2>; };
close(FL2);

my @array;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', $fle1 || die "Error: Couldn't read and write \"$fle1\" file: $!";
my $str = join "\n", @array;

$str=~s#^([^\s]+)\s(.+)$# my $fulcnt=$&;

    if($flecnt2=~m/^$1\s+(.+)$/m)
    {
        $fulcnt .= "\n$&";
    }
    ($fulcnt);
    #egm;

@array = split/\n/, $str;
untie @array;
```